# How to generate test fixtures to mock a REST API in an AngularJS project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, rest

I'm interested in learning more about how to write good unit tests for an AngularJS project.

We are using Karma, but currently we do not have an instructure for generating fixtures to mock our REST API.
So, I ended up including the fixtures in my test setup, for example:

```
var joesBankAccount = {
    addressUuid : 'test-xyz
    accountHolder : 'Joe',
    accountNumber : '123',
    iban : 'DE-TEST-123',
    bic : 'ABC',
    bankCode : '123456',
    bankName : 'MyBank',
    bankCountry : 'Deutschland',
    sepaMandat : {}
  };
```

I'm not sure whether that technique works very well once the REST API changes. I would prefer to only specify what I need for my tests, and let the other parts be provided by a test data builder (e.g., something like Factory Girl for Ruby).

So, I would prefer to write something minimal like this:

```
var joesBankAccount = bankAccountFixture.create({
  accountHolder: 'Joe',
  accountNumber: '123'
});
// mock REST service
// ...

// some action
// ...

expect(scope.accountHolder).toBe('Joe');
expect(scope.accountNumber).toBe('123');
```

Can you recommend a Javascript library for fixture generation? Or do you think  a library is not actually needed?

If you can recommend some well-tested open-source projects that use AngularJS with a REST service backend, it would also be great.

**UPDATE:**

After contemplating over Engineer's nice lightweight solution with `angular.extend` and `angular.copy`, I wonder if my actual example is misleading. Currently, our REST implementation more or less returns flat JSON objects. However, when I look at other REST APIs, the results are more structured, and they can also return collections.

In other words, as long as the REST response is easy as in my example, a library cannot offer very much. However, in general, the response will be more complicate, so maybe libraries still have some edge. (?)

(On the other hand, if the response from the REST service becomes too complicated, from what I hear, it is recommended to encapsulate the logic in a service. Then you can just mock the service, and again end up with an simple example.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you really want to achieve, but I think you need [angular.extend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) function.So if you have some *full* object like a:

```
var joesBankAccount = {
    addressUuid : 'test-xyz',
    accountHolder : 'Joe',
    accountNumber : '123',
    iban : 'DE-TEST-123',
    bic : 'ABC',
    bankCode : '123456',
    bankName : 'MyBank',
    bankCountry : 'Deutschland',
    sepaMandat : {}
};
```

You can do your *minimal changes* by this way:

```
var changedJoesBankAccount = angular.extend(angular.copy(joesBankAccount), {
    accountHolder : 'John',
    accountNumber : '234'
});
```

Comment: Interesting, that is a very lightweight solution. I will give it a try. Maybe there is no need for an external library. (However, my example could be misleading, as it is just a flat JSON object. Libraries could do better if the REST response is more structured, or if the REST resource is returning collection+JSON.) Still, very good answer! :-)